# Align a layout with a child of another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Is there a way to align a layout with a child of another layout?
I have created an example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#7F000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        <View 
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#00FF00"/>
        <View 
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#00FF00"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rel2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#7F0000FF"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view2">

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I try to align the top of the RelativeLayout rel2 with the top of view2, but RelativeLayout don't enable to do that.

I have :

[image]

I want :

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Simply **don't nest** other 2 RelativeLayouts in the main one. Perfect. And **faster**.

Comment: do you want the rel2 width to be match parent or the width of rel1 .?

Comment: have you check below http://stackoverflow.com/a/36837747/2826147 answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can't.

> Layout constraints in a given RelativeLayout should reference other
>   views within the same relative layout (but not itself!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can't do that from the xml file, but I am sure that you can set at runtime the `LayoutParams` of the `rel2` to match the `LayoutParams` of `view2`, and set the root layout to `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Take **LinearLayout** as parent than Use two **RelativeLayout** in Child,

Use `android:weightSum` in **LinearLayout** with `android:orientation`.

Now, check this xml, you will get your required output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.4"
        android:gravity="center">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel21"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:background="#7F0000FF" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="#7F000000"
        android:gravity="center">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#00FF00" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view"
            android:background="#7F0000FF">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="#00FF00" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my absence, it can be a solution, but it's not as flexible as I expected.
By exemple, if you add a new green square, or if you change the layout_marginBottom, you loose the horizontal blue line alignment.
I expect to have a blue line wich it position totally depends on a green square position.

Comment: I don't know, what you want to do after you achieve this. We generally answer what is required in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="#7F000000"
    android:gravity="center">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#00FF00" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:background="#00FF00" />


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:background="#7F0000FF">

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```